# Как добавить функцию блокировки (ban) при подборе логина и пароля в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Как добавить функцию блокировки (ban) при попытке подбора логина и пароля, к примеру если пользователь пытался войти 15 раз с неверным логином и паролем (`if not result:`)

Функция входа:

```
def access_password_username(message, username):
    сon = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATA_BASE)
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT full_name from users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;"""
    cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    if not result:
        msg = "⚠️ Ошибка.\n Неверно веден Логин или Пароль."
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=st, parse_mode='HTML')
    else:
        for ln in result:
            msg = f"✅ Вход выполнен под {ln[0]}"
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=kb_student, parse_mode='HTML')
            return
```

Есть такая функция ban:

```
def blocked(message):
    try:
        db = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASE, check_same_thread=False)
        sql = db.cursor()
        sql.execute("SELECT user_id FROM USERS WHERE messageid = ?",(message.reply_to_message.message_id,))
        db.commit()
        Lusers = sql.fetchall()
        for i in Lusers:
            sql.execute("SELECT user_id FROM blocked WHERE user_id = ?",(i[0],))
            if sql.fetchone() is None:
                try:
                    bot.send_message(i[0],settings.BAN)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, settings.Y_BAN + str(i[0]))
                    sql.execute("INSERT INTO blocked VALUES (?)",(i[0],))
                    db.commit()
                except:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, settings.Y_BAN + str(i[0]))
                    sql.execute("INSERT INTO blocked VALUES (?)",(i[0],))
                    db.commit()
                    continue
        sql.close()
        db.close()
    except Exception as ee:
        # print("error in block" + str(ee))
        return
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что функция ban уже есть, и вы отсюда её хотите вызывать? Если да, то просто цикл нужен.

Comment: @Сергей Да есть, но не зною подойдет ли она, она рассчитана на ручное добавление (в ответ на сообщение прописывается `/ban`)

Comment: Понял, то есть вопрос больше о функции, чем о том, как 15 раз делать. Тогда советую обновить вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал такой функционал, `NUMBER_OF_BAN_TO_SAVE` = 15, в `if not result:` добавил `add_saved_ban(user_id, username, password)`

```
def get_saved_ban(user_id):
    sql = """SELECT user_id FROM saved_ban WHERE user_id = ?"""

    saved_ban_raw = DBManager.execute_sql(sql, (user_id,)) or []
    saved_ban = []
    for ban in saved_ban_raw:
        saved_ban.append(ban[0])

    return saved_ban

def add_saved_ban(user_id, username, password):
    user_saved_ban = get_saved_ban(user_id)

    if username in user_saved_ban:
        return

    sql = """INSERT INTO saved_ban(user_id, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"""

    DBManager.execute_sql(sql, (user_id, username, password,))

    if len(user_saved_ban) == (settings.NUMBER_OF_BAN_TO_SAVE - 1):
        add_user_ban(user_id)

def add_user_ban(user_id):
    sql = """INSERT INTO USER_BAN (user_id) VALUES (?)"""

    return DBManager.execute_sql(sql, (user_id,))
```